# How do I prevent summary (or scope) "proliferation" migrating from tf.scalar_summary to tf.summary.scalar?

Tags: logging, tensorflow, tensorboard

Back [before 2016-11-30](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/deprecated/scalar_summary) I could use TensorFlow/TensorBoard code something like the following to create a single scope containing a variable 'global_step_at_epoch' that showed the global step reached at each epoch of my model runs.

But since replacing `scalar_summary` with `summary.scalar`, as below, I get a new scope for each epoch. So that after `n` epochs have completed, I get scopes, and TensorBoard panels, for 'global_step_at_epoch', 'global_step_at_epoch_1', 'global_step_at_epoch_2', ... 'global_step_at_epoch_n', each with a single point.

How do I migrate from `scalar_summary` to `summary.scalar` so that the code below (or something like it) produces consolidates all of the individual scopes into a single one, as `scalar_summary` used to do?

```
global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False, name='global_step')
test_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(...)

with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True,
                                      log_device_placement=FLAGS.log_device_placement)) as sess:
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

    test_writer.add_summary(sess.run(tf.summary.scalar('global_step_at_epoch', 0)), 0)

    for ep in range(epochs):

        mini_batches = ...

        for mini_batch in mini_batches:

            gs = int(sess.run(global_step))

        test_writer.add_summary(sess.run(tf.summary.scalar('global_step_at_epoch', gs)), ep + 1)
```

Comment: This seems to be related to [issue 8387](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8387).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can already be accomplished with the `tf.name_scope` context manager by naming the manager the first time it is used and simply suing it again when you wish to add new items to the existing scope (without "proliferation"):

```
with tf.name_scope('foo') as a_scope:
   # some graph elements A

# Elsewhere ...

with tf.name_scope(a_scope):
  # additional graph elements B
```

This will place the A and B elements together in a single scope `'foo'`, whereas

```
with tf.name_scope('foo') as:
   # some graph elements A

with tf.name_scope('foo'):
  # additional graph elements B
```

will place the elements in separate scopes, `foo` and `foo_1`, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how it used to work previously, but currently the use of summaries is pretty much aligned with that of the other nodes, in that you create the summary once during a construction phase, and then call it repeatedly in a `Session` during training.

Applying this to your example, this could give:

```
global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False, name='global_step')
test_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(...)
# create summary op once here
gs_summary = tf.summary.scalar('global_step_at_epoch', global_step)

with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True,
                                      log_device_placement=FLAGS.log_device_placement)) as sess:
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    test_writer.add_summary(sess.run(gs_summary), 0)
    for ep in range(epochs):
        mini_batches = ...
        for mini_batch in mini_batches:
            gs = int(sess.run(global_step))
        test_writer.add_summary(sess.run(gs_summary), ep + 1)
```